# URL-embedded credentials

Tags: google-chrome, http, url, web, basic-authentication

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) that HTTP Basic authentication relies on the `Authorization` header to provide credentials from the client to the server.

But it is also possible to embed the credentials in the URL:

```
http(s)://<user>:<password>@<host>/<path>
```

Is it something that is interpreted by the browser and converted into a `Authorization` header or is it directly sent to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But it is also possible to embed the credentials in the URL

Only if the browser is buggy in its support of HTTP, often deliberately so to be backwards compatible with browsers where people mistakenly thought this was a good idea.

It's never been allowed by the HTTP scheme, though the URI syntax more generally does allow user information there.

> Is it something that is interpreted by the browser and converted into a Authorization header.

Yes. If the server at sent a 401 the browser would reply using that username and password. There has been at least one that used to pre-emptively attempt Basic which was obviously a bad idea on top of the existing bad idea.

Comment: Does it mean that, when including credentials in my URL, the browser will make a first request without `Authorization` header to check that the server responds with 401, and if yes make a second request with the `Authorization` header automatically populated?

Comment: @fiddler as I said, generally yes but there's been at least one (safari, but they fixed this security hole since) that would pre-emptively use Basic. Still, there's no sensible reason for depending on this design flaw in real code, so it doesn't really matter...

Comment: I was confused because this initial request does not appear in Chrome's devtools, but I just checked with Wireshark and it is actually performed. Thanks.

Comment: The browser tools often hide the details of network requests, clearing them between repeats and making cache hits look like real hits, etc. Ironic for someone with your username not to try to use Fiddler, which falls somewhere in between the browser tools and wireshark in that it is more web-centric than wireshark, but more literal in what it shows than the browser tools.

Answer (score 5):

The user experience if you type a url with credentials varies by browser and browser settings.

Say you request `http://user:pass@example.com/index.html`.

The browser requests `http://example.com/index.html`, ignoring the credentials for the first request. The server gives a 401 response stating that basic auth is required.
Then depending on the browser and configuration you might experience

- a non-populated username/password prompt for credentials, ignoring the user/pass
- a prompt to the user asking whether to log on to `example.com` as `user` (Firefox)
- automatically login with the credentials.

Then a second request will be made to `http://example.com/index.html` with the `Authorization` header.

Any other client that logs on automatically when given such a URL is using an Authorization header, there's no other way basic auth works.

Comment: But if I go to `https://foo:bar@httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar` in Chrome, the browser does not prompt any credentials