# How do I use this REST authentication style (token immediately following https://)?

Tags: rest, authentication

I'm trying to use this API: https://bibles.org/pages/api/documentation

The docs say to simply do: `https://#{your API token}:bibles.org/v2/versions/eng-GNTD.xml` as their example. However, this doesn't work for me; Chrome and Firefox just forward as if I'm trying to do a google search.

If I do their curl example: `curl -u #{your API token}:X -k https://bibles.org/v2/versions/eng-GNTD.xml`, everything works fine.

I've never seen an authentication style where I passed my token *before* the url. Is there a special way to do this that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your curl command,it looks like you are sending basic authentication with get request.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634710/url-embedded-credentials)

Try

```
https://#{your API token}:X@bibles.org/v2/versions/eng-GNTD.xml
```

Comment: glad it worked:) you might want to let the devs know to update their docs