# request.getHeader("authorization") missing from Tomcat headers

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, basic-authentication

I am very new to Tomcat so please be kind.

My goal is to retrieve the username from basic html authentication from a URL such as:

```
http://username:password@example.com/index.jsp
```

( I want the username value )

I realize this is going to be encoded the authorization header, so just getting the encoded `user:pass` is fine.

When I try to send basic authentication information to my **JSP** page which reads back the headers there is no authorization header ( `request.getHeader("authorization")` )

I have not turned on basic auth in **tomcat** yet, as I am just trying to retrieve the encoded values first. But I assume the header should still be there even if I am not actually using basic auth for anything.

How do I do this? How do I get `request.getHeader("authorization");` to work in **tomcat**?

I am very new to Tomcat and I assume I have overlooked a setting somewhere.

Comment: This is how I added Basic Auth via JDBC (server.xml):
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
   driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://172.16.254.100:3306/db_name"
   connectionName="db_user"
   connectionPassword="db_pass"
   userTable="db_users_table"
   userNameCol="db_user_col"
   userCredCol="db_pass_col"
   userRoleTable="db_role_table"
   roleNameCol="db_role_col">
   <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
    algorithm="MD5"
    iterations="1"
    saltlenght="0" />
   </Realm>

Answer (score 1):

Check on url encoded credentials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634710/url-embedded-credentials).
As @misterben mentions in answer

> The browser requests http://example.com/index.html, ignoring the
>   credentials for the first request. The server gives a 401 response
>   stating that basic auth is required.

So looking at it from the server side, your JSP page *will not* receive the authorization credentials in the first request by the browser. Your server must send a 401 response.

```
response.sendError(401);
```

So it should work once basic auth is enabled.

Comment: I enabled a JDBC realm with basic auth in Tomcat 9 and I started to receive the authorization header.  However it did not work by just sending 401.